# How to install python-mysql on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, pi-2, mysql

I am trying to install python-mysqldb on Raspberry Pi 2.

The sequence of commands I am using is as follows,

sudo apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev build-essential python-dev

Above runs successfully. However following command throws an error.

pip install MySQL-python

Can someone please help me with the issue?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not get it from the repositories?

I would always do that when possible rather than downloading from a third party site.

`sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

To find mysql packages related to Python try

`apt-cache search mysql|grep python`